# How to convert string to date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo to find all the entries today and yesterday. I've followed pymongo tutorial and I can't make this work.

For example I've a sample document like this

```
{
   "_id":"1586856578",
   "threads": "hello"
}
```

Now I've tried to get the document for yesterday using the below code.

```
result = collection.find({"_id": {"$lt": yesterday}}) #<= Not working
```

So I saw that somewhere mongodb support string to date using the `toDate` so I've tried this too.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

dateConversionStage = {"$addFields": {"convertedDate": {"$toDate": "$_id"}}}

result = collection.find({"dateConversionStage": {"$lt": yesterday}})
```

But still returns empty. Help me print all the document which not older than yesterday.

**Update**

```
convertedLong = {"$addFields": {"convertedLong": {"$toDecimal": "$_id"}}}
convertedDate = {"$addFields": {"convertedDate": {"$toDate": "convertedLong"}}}

result = collection.aggregate([convertedLong, convertedDate])
for each in result:
    print(each)
```

Comment: FYI `"_id":"1586856578",`  is timestamp

Comment: For the key/value of `"_id":"1586856578"`,  the value "1586856578" is a string. First, you need to convert it to a number _and_ then use the date function.

Comment: Thanks can you answer your thoughts. I'm very beginning to mongodb

Comment: Use the [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/index.html)  - first convert the string to a number using the `$toLong` _and_ then convert the number to the _date_ type using the `$toDate`.

Comment: I get this when I'm doing that. `Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: Error parsing date string 'convertedLong'; 0: passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed 'c'; 12: Double timezone specification 'g'; 6: Double timezone specification 't'`

Comment: To use _aggregation operators_ within a `find` query, you must use the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator. Note that `$toDate` and `$toLong` are aggregation operators. Also, within the `$expr` you must use the `$gt`, `$lt`, etc., aggregation operators.

Comment: I don't think I converted toDate format correctly because of that error I can't go to `expr` now

Comment: Please post the code you had tried.

Comment: @prasad_ I've updated my code.

Comment: This converts the string date to a `date` field: `{ "$addFields": { "convertedLong": { "$toDate": { "$toLong": "$_id" } } } }`

Comment: Wow that's worked. If you can make it as answer then I will happily accept. :)

Comment: Is it possible to use aggregate and find in same sentence? Or how do I use that in expr

Comment: Yes. Something like this works, e.g.:  `{ $expr: { $lt: [ { "$toDate": { "$toLong": "$_id" } }, ISODate() ] } }` (you have to provide your date value and conditions).

Answer (score 0):

Using PyMongo and three input documents:

```
{ "_id" : "1586908800000" }    // ISODate("2020-04-15T00:00:00Z")
{ "_id" : "1586736000000" }    // ISODate("2020-04-13T00:00:00Z")
{ "_id" : "1585094400000" }    // ISODate("2020-03-25T00:00:00Z")
```

The query to find the documents before yesterday (today is `15-April-2020`):

```
import pymongo
import datetime

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = client.test.myCollection
yesterday = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 14)
result = collection.find( { "$expr": { "$lt": [ { "$toDate": { "$toLong": "$_id" } }, yesterday ] } } )

for doc in result:
    print(doc)
```

The output has two documents.